# Process Working Set Info in LINUX

Tags: c++, linux-kernel

I am trying to obtain the memory working set value for a given PID in my C++ application running on LINUX. In Windows I can get this info using `GetProcessWorkingSetSize` function. Is there anything like this function I can call in LINUX?

Answer (score 1):

The only sensible solution that comes to mind is accessing the relevant information via the `/proc` filesystem. It seems weird that a process would have to read out its own information from `/proc`, though, but I don't know about any other system calls that might make this easier.

The information you're probably most interested in is located in `/proc/[pid]/statm`, which includes :

- total program size,
- resident set size,
- shared pages,
- text (code) size,
- library (unused in Linux 2.6),
- data and stack size,
- dirty pages (unused in Linux 2.6).

Keep in mind that all those measurements are given in the number of pages.

Comment: Note that `/proc/[pid]/status` has this information in a human-readable form

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense. Is there any function that I can call instead of reading the /proc entries? Sysctl is the strongest suspect but I cannot find any way to obtain memory info for a specific process.

Comment: Hi , here I also have same requirement like How we can get the same functionality in Linux for windows API GetProcessWorkingSetSize()? Can anyone suggest a better solution/function which can be used?

Comment: @Anna Seeing how even [Wine returns fake values from this function](https://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/blob/9561af9a7d8d77e2f98341e278c842226cae47ed:/dlls/kernelbase/process.c#l925), I'd assume it's not possible to provide this kind of functionality on a Linux system, at least without modifying the kernel.

Comment: Thanks @DanielKamilKozar for the details